# Generalization of Heron's formula for $n$-gons

Tags: geometry, area, polygons

Recently I knew about [Heron's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) for the area of some triangle, and its generalizations to quadrilaterals by Bretschneider's formula. According to Wikipedia there are also generalizations for pentagons and hexagons inscribed in a circle.

My question: has someone researched on the possibility to generalize this formula for $n$-gons? Is there any underlying reason for this to be a difficult (or impossible) task?

Thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia has a citation to an article written by David Robbins. Did you check that out?

Comment: @CalvinLin yes, but I do not grasp it fully, and the generalizations (just for pentagons and hexagons) look really complex and not "simple" as Heron's or Bretschneider's, which look more usable. I deduce that the task must be difficult, but I would like to have a "simple" explanation of why is so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot a formula for the area of a generic polygon that depends only on the lengths of the sides because polygons are not rigid: they can be deformed by moving the vertices while keeping all side lengths the same.

A formula for the area of cyclic polygons is possible because they are rigid.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00010-020-00771-w) which provides an interesting generalization for cyclic $n$-gons, so I post it as an answer for future reference.